# Send post request with params in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, werkzeug

I have created a post route using werkzeug.

**http://localhost:8000/v1/api/<serial_id>/data**

```
def url_map():
    tenants = [
        Submount(
            "/<serial_id>",
            [
                Rule(
                    "/data",
                    methods=["POST"],
                    endpoint=getData,
                )
            ],
        )
    ]

    api = [Submount("/api", api)]

    rules = [Submount("/v1", api)]
    return Map(rules, strict_slashes=False)


   def getData(self, request, serial_id):
        logger.error('88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888')
        logger.error(serial_id)
        return {'status': 'ok'}
```

I am sending request to the path:

```
requests.post('http://localhost:8000/v1/api/<serial_id>/data',
                                                data= json.dumps({'data':'data'}),
                                                params={'serial_id':1}
                                                )
```

**The problem is instead of printing 1 it print serial_id as <serial_id>.**

```
Expected is:
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
1

Actual is:
88888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888
<serial_id>
```

Comment: `<serial_id>` is what's in the `URL` literally, you need to look in `request` object.

Comment: the url should be look like that ```url = 'http://localhost:8000/v1/api/'+str(serial_id)+'/data' # serial_id is a dynamic value. ```
then ```res = requests.post(url , data= json.dumps({'data':'data'}), params={'serial_id':1})```
then response will ```print(res.text) ```

Comment: When i hit http://localhost:8000/v1/api/1/data, i get serial id as 1. I need a way to set the <serial_id> to 1.

Comment: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/routing/ This is how we define the URLs in werkzeug

Answer (score 2):

As @Md Jewele Islam states in the comments the `url` variable must be like:

```
url = 'http://localhost:8000/v1/api/{}/data'.format(str(serial_id))
```

and the request must be sent like:

```
import json
res = requests.post(url , data= json.dumps({'data':'data'}), params={'serial_id':1})
```

So you can print the response by:

```
print(res.text)
```